# Can you use java FX to create an app that sits on the desktop background?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

We have this requirement where the user wants to see data from a MSSQLServer database right on the desktop when the user logs in.

Very similar of what BGInfo can do for you but instead of system properties data to have some metrics from your operational database.

1. Would JavaFX work for this requirement?
2. Could it be on the background image?  or would it be accessible only via a double click?
3. Can anybody share a very minimalistic example?
4. Any other options I should consider?

Thanks,
-Viriato.

Comment: BGInfo creates a static background image as a combination of it's data and the background image that was set from user. So do you only want to show static data or should it be like a live monitor?

Comment: It should be static data but it will change once a week. Would you still use BGInfo?

Comment: Hm, is the SQLServer running on the same machine where you want to display the data? And what data you want to display?

Comment: No it is not in the same machine. We want to display some metrics around student attendance and staff attendance among others on the desktop so that people is aware once logged in without having to go to a web app for it. Leaders belive that staff behavior will improve if they See those numbers on a daily basis.

Comment: Again I'm not sure. Are the client machines (where the metrics will be displayed) all Windows machines or is it heterogenous? Maybe it's better to create an Application that minimizes to tray. On a mouse over it displays the metrics. But this Application need to be auto started. If they are all on Windows, maybe a C# Dev as a Windows Service will do the job much better.